# Struggling to install geopy

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to install geopy on my computer, but it keeps coming up with this error:
***FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\.certifi'***
However, this file location doesn't exist on my computer and geopy isn't already installed

Can anybody possibly suggest how I could fix this? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Files that start with a `.` are often hidden files, so maybe you just can't see it. See this [link](https://support.eset.com/de/kb6305-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-operating-systems#:~:text=Press%20the%20Windows%20Key%2C%20type,Click%20OK.) how to make them visible. But be careful to not just delete hidden files if you are not sure what they are doing!

Comment: Thank you!!!! Was able to get it sorted now